# Concatenating preprocessor definition and string to create #include path

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I am trying to concatenate a file path for a header file using a preprocessor definition (in this case, the project path) and the filename, but I am persistently getting the following: "warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline". I have tried the following approaches:

```
#define RESOURCE_PATH PROJECT_DIRECTORY "resource.h"
#include RESOURCE_PATH
```

and:

```
#define RESOURCE_FILE "resource.h"
#define RESOURCE_PATH PROJECT_DIRECTORY RESOURCE_FILE
#include RESOURCE_PATH
```

Both of yield warning C4067 on the `#include` line. I have also tried:

```
#define RESOURCE_FILE "resource.h"
#define RESOURCE_PATH PROJECT_DIRECTORY ## RESOURCE_FILE
#include RESOURCE_PATH
```

which also does not work but changes the error to "error C2006: '#include': expected a filename, found 'identifier'".

I have double checked that my source file is UTF-8, so I'm not inadvertently including Unicode characters. PROJECT_DIRECTORY appears to be properly formatted and is the correct path.

I'm using VS2015.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that are causing your problem.

1. You are trying to turn `"A" "B"` into `"AB"`.
2. `#include "A""B"` is not valid syntax.

What you can do, is concatenate `A` and `B` and then turn that into a string literal.

```
#define STR_IMPL(A) #A
#define STR(A) STR_IMPL(A)
```

Then you can do this:

```
#define RESOURCE_FILE resource.h
#define PROJECT_DIRECTORY /foo/bar
#define RESOURCE_PATH STR(PROJECT_DIRECTORY/RESOURCE_FILE)

#include RESOURCE_PATH
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to turn `"A"` into `A` or `"A""B"` into `"AB"` in C++ preprocessor. So, you have to work with tokens without quotes and stringize the result at the end.

Comment: Much to  my amazement [that works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NFTpwjftwUaRIomW).  I never knew that `#include` expanded macros.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, that worked beautifully!